# How can I get a username from LDAP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'd like to ask you how can i dinamically get a username from ldap. As you can see below, i entered the username 'smith2'

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] = 'smith2';
$param = $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]
```

And I can get his first name, like this:

```
   $ldap1 = new ldapl;
   $fname=$ldap1->getFname($param);
```

This is useful because I have some forms with some fields which are filled by default (name, first name, etc).

It must be dynamic. Each person has a PC, so the person Y should see his name, first name, etc The person X his name, first name, etc.

But i don't know how to get the username dinamically. Can you explain it to me?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript won't help you here.

Comment: @jrummell But I thought jQuery was really great and does all things? I know I read that on SO somewhere.

Comment: It's great for client side scripting, but LDAP requires server side  code, php in your case.

Comment: Unless by "dynamically" you mean "ajax", then you could use jQuery to call a php script to get the LDAP information as @Jasper answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can request the username via an AJAX call:

```
var remote_user = '';
$.get('path/to/server-side.php', function (response) {
    remote_user = response;
    /*you can populate your forms with information returned from your PHP script*/
});
```

This code will request information from a PHP script. Your PHP script could just output `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` and that will be the `response` variable in the AJAX callback.

A good way to communicate between PHP script and JavaScript is to use the PHP function `json_encode()` to output your server response. Then use the jQuery method `$.getJSON()` which will automatically parse the response into a JavaScript object that can be iterated through.

Documentation for `$.get()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Documentation for `json_encode()`: http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have a file inc.php with the ldapconn, user and pass to connect to ldap. I have another file class.php with all functions getName($username), getFname($username), etc. Can I use your solution?

Comment: Sure. Have the JavaScript AJAX call a PHP script that includes `class.php` and `inc.php` and uses the `getName()`/`getFname()` functions. In this PHP file, output the results of those functions, whatever you output is what the response will be in your JavaScript. I recommend using `echo json_encode(array('fname' => getFname(), 'lname' => getName()))`; your output will be something like this: `{"fname":"<Fname>","lname":"<Lname>"}` and you can access the data in your Javascript like this: `response.fname` and `response.lname`. Also change `$.get()` to `$.getJSON()` so your JSON will be parsed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I tried to follow what you said in your main post answer, but i do not understand "This code will request information from a PHP script. Your PHP script could just output $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] and that will be the response variable in the AJAX callback." Should I use jquery? Can you give me a little example or do you know a link with some examples? Thank you.